# How to get a row with maximum value for a column

Tags: mysql

This MySQL query is returning 3 rows, but I want to select only that row where `total_votes = max(total_votes);` please tell what should I do for that?

```
SELECT 
      assembly, 
      seat_code, 
      CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name), 
      total_votes, 
      party_id      
FROM (polling JOIN seat USING (seat_id) JOIN candidate USING (candidate_id))
WHERE seat_id = 1;
```

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 2):

Replace your query from

```
SELECT 
      assembly, 
      seat_code, 
      CONCAT(first_name,' ',last_name), 
      total_votes, 
      party_id      
FROM (polling JOIN seat USING (seat_id) JOIN candidate USING (candidate_id))
WHERE seat_id=1;
```

to

```
SELECT 
      assembly, 
      seat_code, 
      CONCAT(first_name,' ',last_name), 
      total_votes, 
      party_id      
FROM (polling JOIN seat USING (seat_id) JOIN candidate USING (candidate_id))
WHERE seat_id=1 AND total_votes=(SELECT MAX(total_votes) FROM <table name>);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `MAX` aggregate:

```
SELECT 
      assembly, 
      seat_code, 
      CONCAT(first_name,' ',last_name)name, 
      MAX(total_votes)total_votes, 
      party_id      
FROM polling JOIN seat USING (seat_id) JOIN candidate USING (candidate_id)
WHERE seat_id=1;
```

> NOTE: There is no need to put parentheses in the JOIN Section.

Comment: this is returning no row

Comment: try putting `MAX` aggregate in `total_votes`. Like `MAX(total_votes)`.Remove also the `HAVING` clause. I've edited my answer.